# Regex Oracle Replace After Occurrence nth

Tags: regex

I am trying to match before occurrence nth and some how it's working as 
https://regex101.com/r/wJ9yS6/192

I tried to apply the regex on oracle regex replace

```
WITH t AS 
(SELECT 'Home|-|Antennas|¿|Directional Antennas|¿|Gain Horn Antennas|¿|Standard Gain Horn Antennas 
 With Coax Input|¿|10 GHz to 15 GHz WR75 Standard Gain Horn Antennas|¿ WR-75 Waveguide Standard Gain 
Horn Antenna Operating From 10 GHz to 15 GHz With a Nominal 15 dB Gain N Female Input'
mycol
FROM dual)
SELECT
     REGEXP_REPLACE (mycol, '(^(?:[^|]*\|){7})(.*)', '\1')
 FROM t;
```

but here is what i got full string i do not know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Oracle regex does not support non-capturing groups. You need to use capturing groups instead.

You may use the `^(([^|]*\|){7}).*` regex (you do not need the last group here, `(.*)` can be written as `.*`):

```
WITH t AS 
(SELECT 'Home|-|Antennas|¿|Directional Antennas|¿|Gain Horn Antennas|¿|Standard Gain Horn Antennas With Coax Input|¿|10 GHz to 15 GHz WR75 Standard Gain Horn Antennas|¿ WR-75 Waveguide Standard Gain Horn Antenna Operating From 10 GHz to 15 GHz With a Nominal 15 dB Gain N Female Input'
mycol
FROM dual)
SELECT
     REGEXP_REPLACE (mycol, '^(([^|]*\|){7}).*', '\1')
 FROM t
```

Output (see [demo online](https://rextester.com/BPD90517)):

[image]

Just note you used a string without line breaks in the regex tester, and your string in the question contains line breaks. You might want to make `.` match any char, you need to pass `n` as the 6th argument:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (mycol, '^(([^|]*\|){7}).*', '\1', 1, 0, 'n')
```

Acc. to the [docs](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php), `n` "*allows the period character (`.`) to match the newline character. By default, the period is a wildcard.*". `1` will start matching from string start position, and `0` will enable replacing all matches (though here, we only need one, you may use `1` here, too, but it does not matter here).

See [another Oracle demo](https://rextester.com/BUABY27995).